# I created a dd array but can't output anything

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86, bios

I'd like to find the largest number in the predefined array and output it to the screen. Now I know for a fact my logic to find the largest number is correct but to output it is like fighting a war which never ends!

```
segment .data


   matrix dd   1,62,3,44,35, \
            61,52,43,45,55, \
            17,23,37,74,65, \
            13,12,93,94,95, \
            31,21,13,14,25 \


segment .bss

holder  resb    4

counter resb    4


segment .text

global _start

_start:

    mov eax, matrix
    call big

big:
    mov esi, holder
    mov edi, counter
    mov edi, 0
    jmp switch

loop:
    inc edi
    cmp esi, [eax + edi]
    jg switch
    cmp edi, 25 
    jle loop
    mov eax, [esi]
    add eax, '0'

    mov eax, 4 ; after some advice from a few forum member i tried the [ebx + ecx *4] but no luck 
    mov ebx, 1 
    mov ecx, eax
    mov edx 
    mov eax, [ebx + ecx * 4]

    int 0x80


switch:
    mov esi, [eax + edi]
    jmp loop


exit:
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Care to tell us anything about the platform and OS you're using? Printing output is one of the most platform-specific things you can imagine.

Comment: @KerrekSB SB wow thats interesting i didnt know i thought this was universal language, im using linux and a nasm compiler for assembly

Comment: How could it be universal? You can write "naked" machine code in assembler (e.g. a bootloader), or you could write a "hosted program" in it, for which any and all details depend on the OS... in a hosted environment, you'd typically want to call some appropriate system call. Anyway, "Linux" is the important piece of information here. Cheers.

Comment: i thought the important info was the fact tht im using nasm

Comment: Hm, maybe, but less so. That just tells us which dialect of source code you need. But the important question is how to make characters appear on the screen, which is an OS/BIOS question :-)

Comment: lol so im guessing you wouldnt have any idea either :( , honestly i've tried everything im THIS close to giving up

Comment: Not of the top off my head... Maybe I'll search around a bit in a quiet moment, but I'm sure someone more clued up will be able to answer this before long. Patience :-) Give it at least half a day or so to give everyone a chance to take a look. I'm confident that an answer exists!

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but I figured you might want to know how to find the largest number in a list in a more efficient way:

```
mov     esi, matrix       ; esi now points to the beginning of the matrix
xor     ebx, ebx          ; ebx will mold the max
xor     ecx, ecx          ; ecx is the counter

loop:
  cmp   ecx, 25           ; Make sure the end of the matrix has not been reached
  jge   end_loop          ; If the end has been reached, jump out of the loop

  mov   eax, [esi+ecx*4]  ; Read the next DWORD from the matrix
  cmp   ebx, eax          ; Compare it to ebx (the current max)
  jle   skip              ; If it's not greater than the current max, skip it
  mov   ebx, eax          ; Otherwise, update ebx with the new max

  skip:
  add   ecx, 1            ; incriment the counter
jmp     loop              ; Loop to the end of the matrix

end_loop:

; ebx now contains the max value in the 25 number matrix
```